# Binding String ArrayList to JList

Tags: java, jlist

I have created a client -> server chat room system, and I have a list of currently connected users, which is currently displayed on a button click within a JTextField, this currently works fine and displays the string array. However, I have added another component to my GUI, being a JList. I have been trying to create a method called updateUserList to update the JList with the users that are connected. I have tried to use a DefaultListModel of type String, however this displays nothing in the JList and I am unsure as to why.

Below is the updateUserList method I have created:

```
public void updateUserList()
{
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for(String usernames : users)
        model.addElement(usernames);
    jl_users = new JList<String>(model);
}
```

Please note that model, usernames and jl_users are defined globally, therefore I have not included them in the post.

Comment: There isn't enough code. For starters, it seems strange, that your **update** code creates a completely new JList object. I would rather expect that your application contains a **fixed** JList; and that you only update the model of that JList. That is the whole point of the model approach: you don't throw away your UI components each time you update something. In other words: please turn to the helpcenter to understand how to write "stuff aint working questions; as you are simply not providing enough information for us to really help you.

Comment: My code contains a new JList object as I was under the impression that is how you add items to the JList.

Comment: You do not add new items to a List by creating a new List. Instead, you initially create the list; and later on, you add/remove elements of the list. Long story short: maybe you want to simply read a tutorial on this stuff? 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `DefaultListModel`? 
If you want a simply List just use it like this

```
public void updateUserList()
{
  jl_users = new JList<String>(users.toArray(new String[users.size()]));
}
```

or straight forward

```
 jl_users = new JList(users.toArray());
```